# Why solidity 0.5.0 not working in remix?

Tags: solidity, remix

When I select the solidity version 0.5.0 in the remix, it never loads. New version is already released, so why is it not loading in the remix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a bug, look in the browser js console.

For now I am using `v0.5.0-nightly.2018.11.13+commit.ac980fb8.js`, try here https://remix.ethereum.org/#optimize=true&version=soljson-v0.5.0-nightly.2018.11.13+commit.ac980fb8.js

Answer (score 1):

you can use https://remix-alpha.ethereum.org for now. Remix release should be ready soon

Answer (score 1):

Remix 0.7.5 was released. solidity 0.5.0 support and some more. checkout here https://github.com/ethereum/remix-ide/releases/tag/v0.7.5